# Сортировка элементов матрицы С++

Tags: c++, сортировка, матрицы

Нужно переставить столбцы в матрице так, чтобы они шли в порядке убывания суммы столбцов. Всю программу не надо, нужен только алгоритм сортировки.

Comment: это вам лабу такую задали?

Comment: Решение очень сильно зависит от того, как у вас хранится матрица.

Answer (score 3):

Задачу за вас тут решать никто не будет, это не по правилам сайта, Есть разные алгоритмы сортировки, гуглите или вот [ссылка](http://algolist.manual.ru/sort/)

Вариантов масса, например создать структуру привязывающую сумму столбца к его индексу, можно использовать вместо нее `std::pair`
если вам нужно по убыванию то сортировать видимо используя оператор `<`

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int index_;
    double sum_; // или long int или long double, завиит от того какая матрица
} SumIndexBunch ;

bool operator < ( SumIndexBunch& a, SumIndexBunch& b ) { return a.sum_ < b.sum_; }
```

1) использовать массив и применить к нему нужный алгоритм сортировки реализованный самим

2) Ели вам задали в институте лаборторную по сортировке, то видимо не подойдет : использовать `std::vector` таких структур размерностью N (N=количество столбцов), сортировать по полю `sum`_, у `vector` есть метод `sort` он сортирует элементы по убыванию или по возратанию, в зависимости от параметроа шаблона тип `comparer= ( std::less` или `std::greater)` (по умолчанию `less` так что вм не надо будет определять comparer ). для int и производных от него уже определены операторы `<, >` , а вот для вашей структуры придется их переопределить.

3) еть вариант с `std::set`, которая хранит элементы по порядку, но тут загвоздка в том, что быстрый поиск в ней будет только по значению sum_ т.к. 
операторы сравнения нужно определять для них, а поиск по индексу придется писать вручную.